# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID on plesk server

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, plesk

i made a web application using Asp.net in which i am using crystal reports.Crystal Reports are working fine on localhost but i am getting error on the plesk server

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4DB2E2BB-78E6-4AEA-BEFB-FDAAB610FD1B} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

[UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4DB2E2BB-78E6-4AEA-BEFB-FDAAB610FD1B} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).]
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor() +169

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.]
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor() +0
   Report_DetailedReport_DetailReport.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +78
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +52
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +97
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +61
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +693
```

[image]

we tried almost every possible solution available on internet. we also want to know that does crystal reports really runs on Plesk server? we have installed exact same version of crystal report in 32 bit i.e. Crystal Report 13.0.31.4010